# NVidia drivers not working on Ubuntu 21.04. But all is good with Monjaro & Pop OS

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, 21.04, dkms

I have ASUS ROG Zephyrus G15 with NVIDIA RTX 3060 Max-Q.
And drivers is not working here.

How I know it:

```
> nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

When I try to install nvidia driver(every version) with apt, got error(warning) about skipping build:

```
Warning: The home dir /nonexistent you specified can't be accessed: No such file or directory
Adding system user `nvidia-persistenced' (UID 127) ...
Adding new group `nvidia-persistenced' (GID 134) ...
Adding new user `nvidia-persistenced' (UID 127) with group `nvidia-persistenced' ...
Not creating home directory `/nonexistent'.
Setting up nvidia-dkms-460 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
Loading new nvidia-460.91.03 DKMS files...
Building for 5.13.15-051315-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Module build for kernel 5.13.15-051315-generic was skipped since the
kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
Setting up libnvidia-encode-460:amd64 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-encode-460:i386 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-driver-460 (460.91.03-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.33-0ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.139ubuntu3) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.15-051315-generic
```

It says that headers are not installed, but:

```
> sudo apt install linux-headers-5.13.15-051315
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-5.13.15-051315 is already the newest version (5.13.15-051315.202109080732).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Is the problem in kernel name? I installed it via Ubuntu Mainline, because such kernel supports my wifi module.

```
> uname -r
5.13.15-051315-generic
```

Some more info:

```
> sudo dkms status
nvidia, 460.91.03: added
> sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list fb
       configuration: depth=32 latency=0 mode=2560x1440 visual=truecolor xres=2560 yres=1440
       resources: iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fe0-fdf memory:fb000000-fbffffff memory:fc00000000-fdffffffff memory:fe00000000-fe01ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:fc000000-fc07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Cezanne
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: c4
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: iomemory:fe0-fdf iomemory:fe0-fdf irq:52 memory:fe10000000-fe1fffffff memory:fe20000000-fe201fffff ioport:c000(size=256) memory:fc500000-fc57ffff
```

Also, I have tried Monjaro and Pop OS, here driver works perfectly, but I really want to use Ubuntu.

So, any thoughts, guys?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The best way to install the proprietary drivers is during system installation by choosing the proprietary driver. After-the-fact, you can install the drivers with `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`. Please try this and report back.

Comment: It's 21.04 supposed to have linux 5.11? How did 5.13 get there?

Comment: @Nmath, I have already done that. Tried to install drivers while Ubuntu installation, and tried autoinstall(especially it will run the same apt commands).
But, I didn't check driver running immediately after OS installation. I will try to drive back kernel and install drivers. (will post results here)

Comment: @mikewhatever, yeah, but as I said in question, I have installed it via Ubuntu Mainline (GUI),because my WIFI works only on kernels higher 5.13